# Using xmlstarlet non XML compliant documents (XHTML)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, xhtml, xmlstarlet

I have non XML compliant documents (XHTML pages) with improperly closed tags,img, br, hr.
I need close image, hr, and br tags properly, with `'/>'`
I tried xmlstarlet, it does the job, but alters XML declaration header.
So I have original code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
<body>
```

if I run command `xmlstarlet fo --recover --html file.xhtml`,
the output is incorrect, have 2 declaration lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"??>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
```

if I run `xmlstarlet fo --omit-decl --recover --html file.xhtml`,
the output is also incorrect, as declaration need be the first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"??>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
```

So I need to do post-processing, swap the first and second lines. What bash command can help here? Please specify command syntax for bath processing files and editing in place.
P.S. why xmlstarlet put 2 question mark chars at the end of declaration? ("no"??>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to append `| sed -n '1{h;d};2{p;g};p'`.

Comment: how to run this command on multiple .xhtml files in batch? `xmlstarlet fo --omit-decl --recover --html file.xhtml`

Comment: Perhaps `sed '1h;1d;2G' file`?

Comment: it works, `sed -i -n '1{h;d};2{p;g};p' *.xhtml` What means `-n` option in this context?

Comment: @minto: Suppress automatic printing of pattern space (current row). See `man sed`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zE 's/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/m' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and swap the contents of line 1 and 2.

N.B. The `m` flag allows `.*` to  refer to lines contents.

Comment: works ok. What means -z option in this context?

Comment: @minto as I said _"slurp the file into memory"_ see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options) for command line options